# 'Var' must be initialized Kotlin

Tags: java, class, kotlin, methods, instance

Some of you can help me with this little problem? I'm very new to Kotlin and Android development! I don't understand why this snippet of code returns me the following error:

```
class Catalog {
var musicList: List<Music> = ArrayList()
}

class Music{
    var id: String = ""
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {  
    var test: Catalog
    test.musicList[0] = "1"  
}
```

ERROR:

```
Variable 'test' must be initialized
```

What is wrong? 
Thank you all!

Comment: You didn't initialize `test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate it before invoking the getter of `musicList`:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {  
    var test = Catalog()
    test.musicList[0] = "1"  
}
```

Furthermore, if you are not re-assigning the value of `test` you can declare it as `val`:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {  
    val test = Catalog()
    test.musicList[0] = "1"  
}
```

You will have other 2 errors after that:

1. since `List` is immutable so you can't use the operator `[]` to assign a value

To solve it, you can use `MutableList` instead of `List`.

```kotlin
class Catalog {
    val musicList = mutableListOf<Music>()
}
```

2. You haven't an item at index 0 so you would get an out of bounds exception.
   To solve it, you can add your element:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {  
    var test = Catalog()
    test.musicList += Music("1")  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in Kotlin you can init variable in two ways.

1. init with default value like... var temp:String = ""
2. init with lateinit keyword(means you will init later) like... lateinit var temp:String

in your case you don't user lateinit So, you need to init your variable with a default value

```
var test = Catalog()
```

or if you want to init as null

```
var test:Catalog? = null
```